# How to hide DIV with another button than the one that show it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

I have several DIV that open with a specific button to each. 
When I click on one of them, the specific DIV appears. I'm looking to close the open DIV when I click on another button. How can I do that?

for the moment when I click on the first button the DIV appears and when I click on the second button the first DIV stay displayed and the second DIV appear below.

You can see the website here : www.coramp.eu to see what happen.

I'm using slideToggle to show the DIVs.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#eds").click(function(){
    $("#edsContenu").slideToggle(500);
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#bridge").click(function(){
    $("#bridgeContenu").slideToggle(500);
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#stress").click(function(){
    $("#stressContenu").slideToggle(500);
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#sante").click(function(){
    $("#santeContenu").slideToggle(500);
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#cosmeto").click(function(){
    $("#cosmetoContenu").slideToggle(500);
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#polymere").click(function(){
    $("#polymereContenu").slideToggle(500);
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#vegetal").click(function(){
    $("#vegetalContenu").slideToggle(500);
  });
});
```

```css
.vignettesContenus {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #00011f;
  display: none;

}

#contenus{
  background-color: #e8f1fa; 
  color : black;
  font-size: 28px;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>



<section id="vignettes"> 

   <div id="discovered" >

    <div id="file" class ="container">
     <input id="eds" type="image" src="IMAGES/PNG/eds.png" alt="EDS system" height="250px" width="250px"/>
    </div>


    <div id="file" class ="container">
     <input id="bridge" type="image" src="IMAGES/PNG/pont.png" alt="pont photonique"  height="250px" width="250px"/>
    </div>


   </div>

   <div id = "research">

    <div id="file" class ="container">
     <input id="stress" type="image" src="IMAGES/PNG/eau.png" alt="eau photonique" height="250px" width="250px" />
    </div>


    <div id="file" class ="container">
     <input id="sante" type="image" src="IMAGES/PNG/syst_biologique.png" alt="Photonic Biological system" height="250px" width="250px"/>
    </div>

   

    <div id="file" class ="container">
     <input id="cosmeto" type="image" src="IMAGES/PNG/principes_actifs.png" alt="Principe actif" height="250px" width="250px"/>
    </div>
  

    <div id="file" class ="container">
     <input id="vegetal" type="image" src="IMAGES/PNG/vegetal.png" alt="étude photonique des végétaux" height="250px" width="250px" />
    </div>
  

    <div id="file" class ="container">
     <input id="polymere" type="image" src="IMAGES/PNG/polymere.png" alt="étude photonique des polymères" height="250px" width="250px"/>
    </div>

   </div>

   
  </section>

  <section id="contenus">

   <div id="edsContenu" class="vignettesContenus">

    <section id="content">

     <div id="text">
     
      <p>EDS©, pour Electrophotonic DataPhoton System » est un dispositif unique permettant d’acquérir, dans le spectre UV, les luminescences d’un corps soumis à son action. Ces luminescences sont caractéristiques de l’objet étudié. <br><br> Le schéma ci-dessous montre le processus de capture d'images utilisé par notre dispositif patenté EDS.</p>

     </div>
    </section>

   </div>


   <div id="bridgeContenu" class="vignettesContenus">

    <section id="content">

     <div id="text">

      <p>Les ponts photoniques constituent une découverte importante sur laquelle une communication a été présentée, en 2014, à l’occasion d’une rencontre internationale organisée par la Bioelectromagnetic Society en Afrique du Sud.<br><br>
      Des ponts photoniques peuvent apparaître ou non, dans le spectre UV, lorsque deux produits ou un système biologique et un produit sont placés à proximité l’un de l’autre sur une électrode spécifique appelée « support de conteneurs » et qu’un champ électromagnétique important est généré. </p>

      

     </div> 
    </section>

   </div>


  <div id="stressContenu" class="vignettesContenus">
   <section id="content">
   
    <div id="text">

     <p>Tous les liquides, y compris les huiles et huiles essentielles, peuvent faire l’objet d’investigation photonique avec le dispositif EDS©. Outre leurs valeurs énergétiques (au sens électron / photon), un rapport de synthèse détaillé peut être réalisé comprenant un ensemble d’indicateurs tels que celui d’une validation intra-lot par exemple.</p><br><br>
     Voici quelques exemples de captation réalisés à partir de différents types de liquide :<br><br>
              <h3> Survolez les vignettes pour obtenir les légendes</h3>

    </div>    
   </section>

  </div>

  <div id="santeContenu" class="vignettesContenus">

   <section id="content">
   
   <div id="text">

    <p> Avec le dispositif EDS©, il est possible de visualiser les luminescences émergeant de l’extrémité des doigts d’une personne. Une fois enregistrées, ces luminescences peuvent être quantifiées sectoriellement et corrélées avec un état d’être du moment.</p>

             <h3> Survolez les vignettes pour obtenir les légendes</h3>


   </div>    
  </section>

  </div>


  <div id="cosmetoContenu" class="vignettesContenus">

   <section id="content">
   
   <div id="text">

    <p>Les effets de couronne obtenus avec le dispositif EDS© montrent des géométrisations, des valeurs énergétiques (au sens électron / photon) et d’autres caractéristiques propres à chaque produit. Tous ces éléments sont des paramètres importants qui peuvent être utilisés dans le cadre de l’optimisation d’un produit (par exemples : tester différents excipients ou conditionnements, vérifier le comportement dans le temps, etc...)</p>

   </div>    
  </section>

  </div>


   <div id="polymereContenu" class="vignettesContenus">
    
    <section id="content">
   
   <div id="text">

    <p>Avec le dispositif EDS©, la matière inerte peut être observée sous un œil nouveau en mettant en évidence des éléments difficilement accessibles autrement.
    A titre d’exemple, voici deux échantillons d’un même polymère (l’un primérisé, l’autre non) avec des différences photoniques suffisamment significatives pour les caractériser, là où aucun marqueur physico- chimique n’est à même de le faire.</p>

   </div>    
  </section>

   </div>

   <br>

   <div id="vegetalContenu" class="vignettesContenus">
    
    <section id="content">
   
   <div id="text">

    <p>Les végétaux et tout ce qui concerne la biodiversité en général se prêtent aux investigations menées avec le dispositif EDS©.
    Comme le montrent les images ci-dessous, plusieurs types de travaux peuvent être menés pour définir, par exemple, la signature photonique d’une espèce ou encore son niveau de vitalité.</p>

   </div>    
  </section>


   </div>


  </section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#bridge").click(function(){

     /// this checks if a DIV is open
     /// when true it closes the DIV
     if(window.openDIV){
        window.openDIV.slideToggle(500);
     };

     /// opening new DIV
     $("#bridgeContenu").slideToggle(500);

     /// This sets the new opened DIV
     window.openDIV = $("#bridgeContenu");
   });
});
```

Just do that on every DIV in your code and it should work like a charm

Comment: perfect !! thanks !! I found another mean but your code is cleanest :-D thanks

Comment: @Haox don't pollute the global scope by adding properties directly to `window` object to track the open div.

Comment: @NikxFabrizio, you're totally right, but in his case it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type=image]').click(function() {
    var contentID = `#${this.id}Contenu`;
    var isContentVisible = $(contentID).is(':visible');
    if (!isContentVisible) {
      $('div[id$=Contenu]').slideUp(500);
      $(contentID).slideDown(500);
    } else {
      $(contentID).slideUp(500);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.vignettesContenus {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #00011f;
  display: none;
}

#contenus {
  background-color: #e8f1fa;
  color: black;
  font-size: 28px;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>



<section id="vignettes">

  <div id="discovered">

    <div id="file" class="container">
      <input id="eds" type="image" src="IMAGES/PNG/eds.png" alt="EDS system" height="250px" width="250px" />
    </div>


    <div id="file" class="container">
      <input id="bridge" type="image" src="IMAGES/PNG/pont.png" alt="pont photonique" height="250px" width="250px" />
    </div>


  </div>

  <div id="research">

    <div id="file" class="container">
      <input id="stress" type="image" src="IMAGES/PNG/eau.png" alt="eau photonique" height="250px" width="250px" />
    </div>


    <div id="file" class="container">
      <input id="sante" type="image" src="IMAGES/PNG/syst_biologique.png" alt="Photonic Biological system" height="250px" width="250px" />
    </div>



    <div id="file" class="container">
      <input id="cosmeto" type="image" src="IMAGES/PNG/principes_actifs.png" alt="Principe actif" height="250px" width="250px" />
    </div>


    <div id="file" class="container">
      <input id="vegetal" type="image" src="IMAGES/PNG/vegetal.png" alt="étude photonique des végétaux" height="250px" width="250px" />
    </div>


    <div id="file" class="container">
      <input id="polymere" type="image" src="IMAGES/PNG/polymere.png" alt="étude photonique des polymères" height="250px" width="250px" />
    </div>

  </div>


</section>

<section id="contenus">

  <div id="edsContenu" class="vignettesContenus">

    <section id="content">

      <div id="text">

        <p>EDS©, pour Electrophotonic DataPhoton System » est un dispositif unique permettant d’acquérir, dans le spectre UV, les luminescences d’un corps soumis à son action. Ces luminescences sont caractéristiques de l’objet étudié. <br><br> Le schéma
          ci-dessous montre le processus de capture d'images utilisé par notre dispositif patenté EDS.</p>

      </div>
    </section>

  </div>


  <div id="bridgeContenu" class="vignettesContenus">

    <section id="content">

      <div id="text">

        <p>Les ponts photoniques constituent une découverte importante sur laquelle une communication a été présentée, en 2014, à l’occasion d’une rencontre internationale organisée par la Bioelectromagnetic Society en Afrique du Sud.<br><br> Des
          ponts photoniques peuvent apparaître ou non, dans le spectre UV, lorsque deux produits ou un système biologique et un produit sont placés à proximité l’un de l’autre sur une électrode spécifique appelée « support de conteneurs » et qu’un
          champ électromagnétique important est généré. </p>



      </div>
    </section>

  </div>


  <div id="stressContenu" class="vignettesContenus">
    <section id="content">

      <div id="text">

        <p>Tous les liquides, y compris les huiles et huiles essentielles, peuvent faire l’objet d’investigation photonique avec le dispositif EDS©. Outre leurs valeurs énergétiques (au sens électron / photon), un rapport de synthèse détaillé peut
          être réalisé comprenant un ensemble d’indicateurs tels que celui d’une validation intra-lot par exemple.</p><br><br> Voici quelques exemples de captation réalisés à partir de différents types de liquide :<br><br>
        <h3> Survolez les vignettes pour obtenir les légendes</h3>

      </div>
    </section>

  </div>

  <div id="santeContenu" class="vignettesContenus">

    <section id="content">

      <div id="text">

        <p> Avec le dispositif EDS©, il est possible de visualiser les luminescences émergeant de l’extrémité des doigts d’une personne. Une fois enregistrées, ces luminescences peuvent être quantifiées sectoriellement et corrélées avec un état d’être
          du moment.</p>

        <h3> Survolez les vignettes pour obtenir les légendes</h3>


      </div>
    </section>

  </div>


  <div id="cosmetoContenu" class="vignettesContenus">

    <section id="content">

      <div id="text">

        <p>Les effets de couronne obtenus avec le dispositif EDS© montrent des géométrisations, des valeurs énergétiques (au sens électron / photon) et d’autres caractéristiques propres à chaque produit. Tous ces éléments sont des paramètres importants
          qui peuvent être utilisés dans le cadre de l’optimisation d’un produit (par exemples : tester différents excipients ou conditionnements, vérifier le comportement dans le temps, etc...)</p>

      </div>
    </section>

  </div>


  <div id="polymereContenu" class="vignettesContenus">

    <section id="content">

      <div id="text">

        <p>Avec le dispositif EDS©, la matière inerte peut être observée sous un œil nouveau en mettant en évidence des éléments difficilement accessibles autrement. A titre d’exemple, voici deux échantillons d’un même polymère (l’un primérisé,
          l’autre non) avec des différences photoniques suffisamment significatives pour les caractériser, là où aucun marqueur physico- chimique n’est à même de le faire.</p>

      </div>
    </section>

  </div>

  <br>

  <div id="vegetalContenu" class="vignettesContenus">

    <section id="content">

      <div id="text">

        <p>Les végétaux et tout ce qui concerne la biodiversité en général se prêtent aux investigations menées avec le dispositif EDS©. Comme le montrent les images ci-dessous, plusieurs types de travaux peuvent être menés pour définir, par exemple,
          la signature photonique d’une espèce ou encore son niveau de vitalité.</p>

      </div>
    </section>


  </div>


</section>
```

Just replace your jquery code with this one.

Comment: when a section is displaying how can I hide it with a click on the matching button?

Comment: @Haox slide up the current div if it's already visible, i've updated the code snippet.